# HttpClient in Silverlight is buffering data for MJPEG stream

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, video, video-streaming

When using HttpClient to download a live MJPEG stream in Silverlight it buffers about 260,000 bytes each time before letting me access the bytes to convert to an image. This causes a problem because it will display 16 images at once. In WPF with the same code this doesn't happen, each image is being read then displayed.

I tried reducing the size of,

```
httpClient.MaxResponseContentBufferSize
```

but that did nothing. I used the following examples to create my MJPEG decoder,

http://mjpeg.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#

(It's WPF, but I converted this to Silverlight)

http://blogs.infosupport.com/writing-an-ip-camera-viewer-in-c-5-0/

Both example had the same problem and both worked in WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing this worked,

```
HttpWebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);
```